# How to echo a table in two piece separated code in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Now I wish to construct a list of tables under nested `while` loop and `if-else` condition with PHP, the format of the code is as below:

```
while(){
   if (){
       ..... // extract the data
       while(){

          construct a table using the data extracted above
       }
   }
   elseif (){
       ..... // extract the data
       while(){

          construct a table using the data extracted above
       }
   }
}
```

Specifically, in the inner while loop the code is:

```
while ( $chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatQ)) 
        {
            echo 
            "<table class='table table-hover' >"
                ."<td>"
                    .$conver['sender_name']."\t".$chat['sender']."\t".$chat['send_time']."\t".$chat['content']
                ."</td>"
                ."<td>"
                    ."<form id='join' action='group_chat.php' method ='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8'>"
                         // post the group id
                        ."<input type='hidden' name='group_id' id='group_id' value=".$conver['sender_id']."/>" 
                        ."<button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Enter</button>"
                    ."</form>"
                ."</td>"        
            ."</table>";
        }
```

But the result is very ugly:
[image]

The problem is that the `Enter` button is associated with each message. But what I want is that after displaying all the messages, there is a `Enter` button which can direct to the specific group. But I don't know how to separate the code. Could you please do me a favor? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
echo '
<form>
    <table>';
while ( $chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatQ)){
    $counter++;
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>
                group_id_'.$counter.'
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="group_id_'.$counter.'" value="'.$conver['sender_id'].'">
            </td>
        </tr>';
}
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit">Enter</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>';   
?>
```

Also you dont have to limit yourself to echo everything in order by setting variables. See example below:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$data = NULL;
while ( $chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatQ)){
    $counter++;
    $data .='
        <tr>
            <td>
                group_id_'.$counter.'
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="group_id_'.$counter.'" value="'.$conver['sender_id'].'">
            </td>
        </tr>';
}
    echo '
<form>
    <table>'.$data.'
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit">Enter</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>';   
?>
```